# object doesn't support this property or method. IE7 retrieving value from multidimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-7, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to retrieve some values from a multi-dimensional array using javascript. I have the following code:

```
var imgArray = [{
    image: '1358267998.jpg',
    table: '1358602091.jpg',
    orientation: 1,
    margin: 182,
    desc: 'First Image, posters',
    title: 'First Image, posters',
    price: '0.00'
}];
var imgNo = 0;
switchImg(imgNo);

function switchImg(imgNo) {
    title = imgArray[imgNo].title;

    //also doesn't work: imgArray[imgNo]['title'];
    //bizarrely, this works: imgArray[imgNo].image;

    $('.pageTitle').html(title);
}
```

It seems that IE7 just cannot retrieve these values... except from the first one, "image"; I can correctly get the value "1358267998.jpg"

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the element with class "pageTitle"?

Comment: ... also you should probably declare "title" with `var`

Comment: Thanks, Pointy. The element is just a h1 heading. This works fine in all modern browsers.

Comment: As per the title, I get the error "object doesn't support this property or method" in IE7 pointing to this line: title = imgArray[imgNo].title; I've stripped all other JS from the page.

Comment: Well your code [works fine in IE7 in this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4q85Q/)

Comment: Thanks pointy. Yep looks OK. However, my client reports that this does not work on his work computer running IE7 + Windows XP. I am currently testing in Browserstack with the same system emulation... and I can confirm it is not working.

Comment: I'm using Windows XP with IE7 to try the jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks, Pointy. On further investigation, this seems to be some other problem with my page. Trying to narrow it down. Thanks for your help.